# Laravel 5.2 Advanced join with another join condition

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-query-builder

so I'm building a query with the querybuilder where I need to count rows from a joined table that has a where condition from another table. I can't join that table in the end because it would result in the wrong rows being compared to this specific join. I thought the advanced join clausule would allow another join to be added in it's own scope but this seems to not be the case.

This is what I tried:

```
$profile = DB::table('users')
      ->select('users.username', 'users.profile_picture', 'users.screen_state',
      'count(replies.id) as replies', 'count(interactions.id) as interactions',
      'count(alerts.id) as alerts', 'count(user__followers.id) as followers',
      'count(user__following.id) as following', 'count(following.id) as volgend')
      ->leftJoin('replies', function($join)
      {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'replies.user_id')
          ->leftJoin('alerts')
          ->on('replies.alert_id', '=', 'alerts.id')
          ->where('replies.user_id', '=', $user->id)
          ->where('alerts.hide', '=', 0);
      })
      ->leftJoin('interactions', function($join)
      {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'interactions.user_id')
          ->leftJoin('alerts')
          ->on('interactions.alert_id', '=', 'alerts.id')
          ->where('interactions.user_id', '=', $user->id)
          ->where('alerts.hide', '=', 0);
      })
      ->leftJoin('alerts', function($join)
      {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'alerts.user_id')
          ->where('alerts.user_id', '=', $user->id)
          ->where('alerts.hide', '=', 0);
      })
      ->leftJoin('user__followers as user__following', function($join)
      {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'user__followers.user_id')
          ->where('user__followers.user_id', '=', $user->id)
          ->where('user__followers.follower_id', '=', $searchid);
      })
      ->leftJoin('user__followers as following', function($join)
      {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'user__followers.user_id')
          ->where('user__followers.user_id', '=', $user->id);
      })
      ->leftJoin('user__followers', function($join)
      {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'user__followers.user_id')
          ->where('user__followers.follower_id', '=', $user->id);
      })
      ->where('users.id', '=', $user->id)
      ->get();
```

I also have this query in raw sql so you can see what I'm trying to achieve:

```
            SELECT u.username, u.profile_picture, u.screen_state,
            (SELECT count(DISTINCT r.id)
                FROM `reply` r
                LEFT JOIN alerts a
                ON r.alert_id = a.alert_content_id
                WHERE r.user_id = :userid AND a.hide=0)
                    AS replies,
            (SELECT count(DISTINCT i.id)
                FROM `interactions` i
                LEFT JOIN alerts a
                ON i.alert_id = a.alert_content_id
                WHERE i.user_id = :userid AND a.hide=0)
                    AS interactions,
            (SELECT count(DISTINCT a.alerts)
                FROM `alerts` a
                WHERE a.user_id = :userid AND a.hide=0)
                    AS alerts,
            (SELECT count(DISTINCT uf.id)
                FROM `user_followers` uf
                WHERE uf.user_id = :userid
                AND uf.follower_id = :searchid)
                    AS following,
            (SELECT count(DISTINCT uf.id)
                FROM `user_followers` uf
                WHERE uf.user_id = :userid)
                    AS volgend,
            (SELECT count(DISTINCT uf.id)
                FROM `user_followers` uf
                WHERE uf.follower_id = :userid)
                    AS followers
                FROM users u
            WHERE id = :userid GROUP BY id
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::leftJoin()
```

So my question is how can i join a table and check for a condition in yet another table?

Comment: Write select statement after left join

Comment: Tried it but it's giving an error on the leftJoin function that has a leftJoin in it.